# How to create dataframes with Google Maps geolocations?

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, google-geolocation

In Python 3 and Pandas I have a dataframe with addresses:

```
import pandas as pd

consolidado = pd.read_excel('empresas_de_seguranca_consolidado_final.xlsx', converters={'cnpj': lambda x: str(x)} )

consolidado.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1226 entries, 0 to 1225
Data columns (total 25 columns):
cnpj                                1226 non-null object
CNAE_principal                      1136 non-null object
nome_empresa                        1226 non-null object
nome_empresa_maiuscula_minuscula    1001 non-null object
estado                              1001 non-null object
indicador                           1147 non-null float64
documento                           1147 non-null object
qualificacao                        1147 non-null object
socio                               1150 non-null object
socio_maiuscula_minuscula           1004 non-null object
data_abertura                       1218 non-null object
logradouro                          1155 non-null object
numero_logradouro                   1155 non-null object
complemento                         646 non-null object
cep                                 938 non-null object
bairro                              1206 non-null object
municipio                           1226 non-null object
regiao                              231 non-null object
telefone                            764 non-null object
email                               344 non-null object
situacao                            1226 non-null object
data_situacao_baixa                 434 non-null object
capital_social                      856 non-null object
cargo_relacionado_socio             190 non-null object
observacao                          327 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(24)
memory usage: 239.5+ KB
```

The complete address is formed by the columns "logradouro" (street, avenue etc.), "numero_logradouro" (place number), "complemento" (address supplement), "bairro" (neighborhood) and "municipio" (city)

Example, the address: "R AURELIO VALPORTO,  51,     LOJA A, MARECHAL HERMES, RIO DE JANEIRO", creates the link: https://www.google.com/maps/place/R.+Aur%C3%A9lio+Valporto,+51+-+LOJA+A+-+Mal.+Hermes,+Rio+de+Janeiro+-+RJ,+21555-560/@-22.8588275,-43.3725532,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x9963aae3b2d379:0x2d6d007bdaa4b68c!8m2!3d-22.8588275!4d-43.3703592

Please, could I access the Google Maps API (Google Street View) to send these complete addresses, and receive the image of the property and link of each address and more geographical location of the addresses (latitude and longitude)?

My intention is to create a dataframe with this data and if possible a folder with the images downloads. The addresses are from Brazil

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
import googlemaps
import google_streetview.api

# Insert your key
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('R JORGE RUDGE, 108, CASA 23, VILA ISABEL, RIO DE JANEIRO')

lat = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
lng = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']

# Define parameters for street view api
params = [{
  'size': '600x300', # max 640x640 pixels
  'location': str(lat)+","+str(lng),
  'heading': '0;90;180;270',
  'pitch': '-0.76',
  'key': '' # insert
}]

# Create a results object
results = google_streetview.api.results(params)

# Download images to directory 'downloads'
results.download_links('downloads')
```